# dominos game: fill a $m \times n$ matrix with $2\times1$ tiles and $m,n$ odd

Tags: discrete-mathematics, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Dominos of size $2 × 1$ can be placed on a $m × n$ board so as to cover two squares exactly. Two players alternate placing dominos. The first one who is unable to place a domino is the loser.

From [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794715/position-games-how-to-fill-a-matrix-with-dominos?noredirect=1&lq=1), I know how to solve the cases: both $m,n$ even, and one even one odd. I'm quite curious about what about both $m, n$ odd? Are there literatures or textbooks which throughly solved this problem?

There are also [posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615242/game-involving-tiling-a-1-by-n-board-with-1-x-2-tiles?rq=1) handle the case $n\times1$.

Comment: The game is known in the literature as Cram, and determining the outcome is an open problem, other than the special cases you already mentioned. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram_(game)#Known_values

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thank you so much!