# What properties can be derived for these recursively defined Nimbers (or Grundy numbers)?

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

We let $a_0 = 0, a_1 = 0, a_n=\text{mex}(\{a_i+a_{n-i-2},i=0\ldots n-2\}),n\geq2$. Now suppose we need to calculate $a_n$ for large $n$ and fast. There have got to be certain shortcuts for that - like being able to move from $a_n$ to $a_{2n}$ in one step or having a closed form for some of these numbers for some $n$s. That's what I'm interested in. Thanks.

EDIT: For those who are new to this whole Nimber thing, as I am, $\text{mex}$ stands for "minimally excluded" and returns minimal non-negative number that is not in the given set. For example, $\text{mex}(\{1,2,4\})=0$ and $\text{mex}(\{0,2,5\})=1$. Also, nimber-addition is just bitwise-xor, so plus-sign in the formula can be changed for $\oplus$. Now if we go back to my sequence, we would have
$$
a_2=\text{mex}(\{0\oplus0\})=1,
$$
$$
a_3=\text{mex}(\{0\oplus0,0\oplus0\})=1,
$$
$$
a_4=\text{mex}(\{0\oplus1,0\oplus0,1\oplus0\})=2.
$$
Similarly, $a_5=0,a_6=3,a_7=1$, and so on.

Comment: in this case all your values will just be $0$, as the two start conditions are $0$

Comment: I assume you mean max? There might be a typo in your formula.

Comment: No, it's $\text{mex}$. Short for "minimum excluded". These are not ordinary numbers, but Nimbers. See wiki for that.

Comment: Interesting. May be good to note that in the question. Most people in my area would probably just assume it was a type because that also parses.

Comment: MJD, $i$ varies from 0 to $n-2$, so you can't have $i=1$ when $n=2$.

Answer (score 1):

This sequence is naturally identical to the sequence of nimbers for a heap game in which, on your turn, you can remove $2$ items from a heap and then optionally split the remainder into two separate heaps of arbitrary sizes. That heap game is extremely famous, and is known as [Dawson's Kayles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal_game#Dawson's_Kayles), or "the heap game with Octal code 0.07". Equivalently, you can imagine this game as placing dominoes on a line of boxes, as in [this other MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/615242/26369).

Very briefly, nimber sequences like this often become periodic after a while, and there is a theorem that says they definitely become periodic if they *look* like they do. This makes it very easy to calculate your sequence for large $n$ quickly. For some more information, see [this community wiki collection of tutorials](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1746959/26369) about nimbers and octal games.

As mentioned in [my answer to that other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/615737/26369), a nearly identical sequence is at [OEIS entry A002187](http://oeis.org/A002187), except the sequence there is missing the $a_0=0$ term. For completeness, here is the beginning of *your* sequence, with $8$ exceptional terms underlined. There are no more exceptions; it continues on with period $34$:
\begin{array}{r|cccc}
 n & \text{0+} & \text{34+} & \text{68+} & \text{102+} \\
\hline
 0 & \underline{0} & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
 1 & \underline{0} & \underline{0} & 8 & 8 \\
 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 3 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 4 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 6 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
 7 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 8 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 9 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 10 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
 11 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
 12 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
 13 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
 14 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
 15 & \underline{0} & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
 16 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\
 17 & \underline{2} & 5 & 5 & 5 \\
 18 & \underline{2} & \underline{2} & 9 & 9 \\
 19 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
 20 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
 21 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 22 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 23 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 24 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
 25 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 26 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
 27 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 28 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 29 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 30 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
 31 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\
 32 & \underline{2} & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
 33 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7  \end{array}