# How to prove that for $n$ even and positive, the first player can guarantee a win?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, combinatorial-game-theory

> Two players take turns placing dominoes on an $n \times 1$ board of
>   squares, where each domino covers two squares and dominoes
>   cannot overlap. The last player to play wins.
>
> (a) Where would you place the first domino when $n = 11$?
>
> (b) Prove that for $n$ even and positive, the first player can guarantee a win.

**My attempt.** I am trying to solve this problem, for the question (a), I figure it out that we should place it in the third or forth position to make sure we can win. However, for question (b), I think the first player should place the domino in the middle of the square and am trying to use complete induction to solve this question but I got stuck.

How to prove that for $n$ even and positive, the first player can guarantee a win?

Answer (score 1):

As regards (b), you are right, if $n>0$ is even, the first player should place the domino in the middle of the board leaving two identical boards $(n/2-1)\times 1$ and then he follows a mirror strategy, that is he replicates each second player's move on the other half of the board.

For (a), read MJD's answer [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615242/game-involving-tiling-a-1-by-n-board-with-1-x-2-tiles). If $n=11$ then putting a domino on the third and fourth squares we leave two boards: $2\times 1$ and $7\times 1$. Since $r_2=1$ and $r_7=1$ and $r_2\oplus r_7=0$, this is a winning move. Also putting a domino on the first and second squares is a nice move because $r_9=0$.
One the other hand, putting a domino on the fourth and fifth squares is not good because $r_3\oplus r_6=1\oplus 3=2\not=0$.

Comment: Yes, but how can I prove it using complete induction. Since n-2/2 can be an odd number, then we can not use the induction hypothesis that is: for every even number n, the first player will always win...

Comment: btw, thank you for modifying my question, it looks better now...

Comment: For (b) there is no need to use induction. Mirror strategy means that the first player replicates the move of the second player on the other half of the board.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. Could you please show me how to prove it with or without induction... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Recall that the last player to play wins. So  by the mirror strategy, if the second player has a move then  the  firts can take the same move on the other side. Eventually the two boards will be full of dominoes (with some $1\times 1$ empty squares) and the second player loses the game.

Comment: @addcrtff Any further doubt?

Comment: No, thank you very much!