# A variation of Nim game

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

There are two players $X$ and $Y$. They write $N$ integers on paper $( A_1 , A_2 , A_3 , ....  A_N )$.

They have also $M$ integers $(B_1 , B_2 , B_3 , .... B_M )$ .

Now, Player $X$ always takes turn first. He can choose any integer $A_i$ from

the list and choose any integer $B_j$ from the second list and change $A_i$ to 
$\dfrac{A_i}{B_j}$

If $B_j$ doesn't divide $A_i$ then he just replaces $A_i$ with
$\Bigl\lfloor{\frac{A_i}{B_j}}\Bigr\rfloor$.

Once some $A_i$ becomes $0$ it can be removed from the list . The player who can

not make any move loses.

What is the solution of this problem ? How can I covert it to some familiar 
Nim problem ?

Comment: Hi -- welcome to math.SE! [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: The same question was posed on the same day: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803182. Please enlighten us as to the source of the problem, and please take note of [our contest problem policy](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16774).

Comment: This was from a contest . It required me to solve at least 1 problem to qualify to the next round.I have solved all three but I don't know how to solve this one. But, I think it's some variation of NIM. So, I need some resources/ideas to solve this problem :-)

Comment: Thanks. If possible, please provide a link to the contest so we can establish when it ends / ended.

Comment: As noted in a comment under the duplicate question linked to above, the contest ended on May 31, so the question can now be answered. Please take our contest problem policy into account in the future.