# High school proof for Sprague–Grundy theorem

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

I'm having a hard time trying to understand the proof given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem#Proof), I have never seen that notation before. I'm having the same problem with other sources.

I completely understand the proof of winning and losing states of Nim game (using XOR) but I can't understand the proof that "every impartial game under the normal play convention is equivalent to a nimber" [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem#Proof). I wonder if there's any high school proof for that.

Comment: [This doesn't give a proof](http://blog.plover.com/math/sprague-grundy.html) but it does give an explanation that might make the proof easier to read.

Comment: Thanks @MJD, I'll take a look.

Comment: A number of different sources are available at [this community wiki post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1746959/26369). If any of them work for you, or if you find another source that does, I recommend posting an answer to your own question.